# Tablesnap not working

Tags: python, cassandra, backup

I'm trying to use tablesnap to make backups but without success. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and after trying the installation of tablesnap as it is described in github, I'm not able to do it. I guess this is due to fact that the package is for Maverick, so I have tried to copy the code and execute it but again without success. It always display the message "INFO Starting up" and seems nothing happen.

I'm sure the problem is my ignorance but, could you help me? Do you know about any document or example of installing and using for backup and recovery?

UPDATE:

The problem was me. Tablesnap was working but there was no IN_MOVED_TO event. So, now, what I'm trying to do is to backup a complete keyspace. I have tried with the "-B" option of tablesnap but still nothing is uploaded to S3. Any idea?

Comment: Your question is actually 13 lines on my screen. Of these lines, only about 4 describe your problem. That's not a good relationship. Your question would at least have been as good if you left out all the "sorry", "I've searched a lot here and there", "thank you", "I hope that" phrases, but it would have cost me 90% less time to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I have updated my question following your advice.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sure the problem is my ignorance of linux, python and cassandra, but I haven't found enough information to make it work or a step by step document

Being blunt here: yes. You've got the answer to your own question. It's complicated to get used to all of that at once, but a step-by-step document won't help you a bit. Really. You need to be familiar with what you're doing, or else you won't be able to do something useful.

To compare: Installing cassandra is like buying a dentist's chair. Even with a very precise step-by-step information on how to set it up and how to place a patient on it, you'll be a terrible terrible threat to your patient's teeth if you have no education as a dentist before.

Cassandra is a mighty tool for large, ditributed systems. Someone who develops for that or even just administrates that needs to have very solid understanding of how to work with his computer in the environment that cassandra runs in. Get yourself used to linux. Then read a lot about cassandra. Then that project is on your level, and you will have success!

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I take care of what you say in your comment and your answer. I'm trying to do what you say to achieve the knowledge I need, but this a long way and I have to practise too in order to learn. Yes, it was my ignorance: the process was working right but there was no IN_MOVED_TO event. So now the question is: how could I backup a complete keyspace as it is now? I have tried with the -B option of tablesnap but nothing is uploaded to S3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I was looking for is very easy. Here is what I have done to make a complete backup of my keyspaces:

```
python tablesnap -k MY_AWS_KEY -s MY_AWS_SECRET -B my_s3_bucket /opt/cassandra/data/my_keyspace/*
```

Just replace /opt/cassandra/data/ with the path to your keyspace and that's all. As simple as this is what I was asking for, so I leave it here in case someone finds it useful.